# Pascal graphic unit

Tags: graphics, pascal, delphi

This is going to be an Object Pascal question again.

I know what you all will say now, "We've got 21st century and you are willing to make graphics in language older than the planet Earth !?".
Well.. yes, but just a simple one, becouse I have to.
I need it in a tiny little game that normal console window, with CRT, is not exacly what I need.

What I want to ask is You is what standard (! no custom extensions !) unit should I use.
Is Graph a good choice ? I've seen many posts about people complainig, is it safe to use ?
I have checked it already by myself and few things got my attention:

- Is graph window name changeable ?
- Is the main console hideable ?
- Can you detect the manual graph close (easly) ?

Maybe you can suggest me some other (better?) graphics unit ?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-sdl/

Comment: Which Pascal implementation do you have in mind? Free Pascal with or without Lazarus? Delphi? Anything else?

Comment: Object Pascal is basicaly used in Lazarus AFAIK. I have already solved the first two problems, thanks to @Marco van de Voort. Unfortunatly I am still having problems with manual graph close when program is doing something, ie. some iterations.

Comment: Borland called it object pascal too, but renamed it to "Delphi language" a while back. FPC didn't follow because "Delphi" is trademarked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the demoes (fpctris,samegame) that come with Free Pascal. They demonstrate a games in a pure console version and a graph version.

1. Don't know
2. On Windows, yes, use "wingraph" instead of "graph"
3. no idea.